# Alternative To .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, yii

I am trying to build mu first web application with yii

From what I understood a .htaccess file must be in the project folder

in the localhost every things work fine, but when I upload the whole project my remote server doesn't accept .htaccess files and I get 404 not found (server error not yii error)

there is an alternative to this problem ?

many thanks in advance

Comment: you push on your server using a ftp client?

Comment: Except for the names, this question has nothing to do with coding or programming, consider moving it to [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). You will do better there.

Comment: yes I amusing ftp client
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no alternative when using a Front Controller pattern. Only on the http server you can redirect all wanted requests to a single central point. It is weird though that you cannot use .htaccess.

One more question: are you using apache or something else as a web server? Because .htaccess is apache specific to the best of my knowledge, for other servers you need differend configuration in differend other places.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply
how to know to version of the web server 
thanks

Comment: hi!
the server is YTS/1.19.11

Comment: YTS (I guess Yahoo Traffic Server), as far as i can see is mostly a reverse/forward proxy, which means that it is not that server that handles your php dispatches. Most likely it is used as a reverse proxy. However, i can see that this is currently under Apache Software Foundation management, and is no longer called Yahoo Traffic Server. It would be helpful to know what actual server you have serving the php requests. You can grab some of these informations from printing out $_SERVER superglobal.

Comment: Btw, the Apache Traffic Server is at version 3.x right now, so if that is what you're running under, i would look for another provider.